# Ionic 4 transparent transparent header

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an Ionic 4 app and I want a transparent header. The Ionic documentation states that 'fullscreen' must be added to the ion-content, and that 'translucent' must be added to the ion-toolbar.

This does not work and always leaves the toolbar at the top. I have added this to the css as well:

```
ion-toolbar {
   --background: transparent;
   --ion-color-base: transparent !important;
}

<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar translucent >
    <ion-buttons slot="start"  (click)="goBack()">
        <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content fullscreen >
</ion-content>
```

The only way I can find that achieves the affect of a transparent header is when I go to the Shadow DOM in chrome and add a background attribute to the class 'inner-scroll'

However there are no variables associated with background color in this class and so I cannot change the background using this method.

How can I make this transparent header/toolbar work!?

***Solution:***

for anyone else having this issue - the documentation is not clear at all. To get a fully transparent functional header:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar translucent>
    <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content fullscreen> </ion-content>
```

No in the css add the following:

```
ion-toolbar {
--ion-toolbar-background-color: transparent;
--ion-toolbar-text-color: white;
}
```

The documentation only specifies the HTML side of things but with the new Shadow DOM in Ionic, variables must be used to changed most of the Ionic component styles.

Comment: Hey can you explain what is UX you are trying to achieve - you want header to have transparent background BUT be still able to see buttons title etc or what?

Comment: Instead of `--ion-toolbar-background-color` it should be `--ion-background-color`, just because of this change I was struggling myself, now everything just fall in place! :)

Comment: Also replace --ion-toolbar-text-color with --ion-toolbar-color

Comment: The solution does not work in Ionic 5.  I had a working solution for Ionic 4 but no idea for ionic 5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try this ?

```
ion-toolbar {
   --background-color: transparent;
   --ion-color-base: transparent !important;
 }
```

Comment: tried this already and it works in making the bar transparent, but then there is still the space where the bar should be. Its then a question of moving the content up, which there is no variable for

Comment: `<ion-toolbar no-padding>`
Did you try this ?

Comment: yes, Ionic 4 has nothing about no-padding. However, the same result. Transparent bar, but still a big space where the bar is

Comment: I ended up removing it completely and manually adding the back button in

Comment: so if everything is ok , please check right answer button :)

Comment: Its not - The tool bar does not function transparently - none of the fixes work

Comment: @user3024827 hey, I'm trying to manually add the back button so I can have a "transparent" toolbar, but it looks like the `ion-back-button` will not show unless it's within `ion-header`, I was curious how you ended up manually adding the back button in? Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

```
...    
<ion-toolbar color="translucent"> 
...
```

and if you want to get rid of the box shadow of your header you can do it in your css like:

```
.header::after {
  background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want translucent header in ionic 4 you need to add the "translucent" property to the header tag, not the toolbar tag.

```
<ion-header translucent="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Toolbar Title</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content fullscreen="true">
    <!-- content here -->
</ion-content>
```

From the ionic doc...
[Translucent](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/header)

Attribute: translucent 
Type: boolean
If true, the header will be translucent. Note: In order to scroll content behind the header, the fullscreen attribute needs to be set on the content. Defaults to false.

Comment: Anyway of doing this without using the IonHeader, since it does some nasty stuff with the styles and the layouts :-/

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me, header is transparent but there was still some white space

```
ion-toolbar {
  --background-color: transparent;
  --ion-color-base: transparent !important;
}
```

but using the ion-toolbar inside ion-content removed it from above the background

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-toolbar slot="fixed">
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm a little late, but just to anyone who is in the same situation with Ionic 5, 6 or later you can do this:

```css
ion-toolbar {
  --opacity: 0;
}
```

And the toolbar background will be transparent. It is in the ion-toolbar [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toolbar)

---

If you needs ion-content overlapps with header, add `fullscreen` props([documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content#fullscreen))

```html
<ion-content fullscreen></ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

In CSS

```
.productHeader {
    --background: transparent;
}
```

Ionic HTML

```
<ion-header no-border>
  <ion-toolbar class="productHeader">
   .
   .
   .
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content fullscreen>
  .
  .
  .
</ion-content>
```

Make sure that you add `fullscreen` in `ion-content` 
and in order to remove shadows that appear in header i have added `no-border`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

 mypage.page.html

```
<ion-header no-border no-shadow>

  <ion-toolbar color="medium">
    <ion-title>My Page</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content fullscreen="true">

</ion-content>
```

Now change the **variable.scss** file of medium color to

```
--ion-color-medium: #ffffff00;
```

Answer (score 0):

I try this and it works

In variables.scss

```
ion-toolbar {
  --background: transparent;
  --ion-color-base: transparent !important;
}
```

In the page

```
<ion-header translucent></ion-header>

<ion-content fullscreen>
    <div class="contenu"></div>
</ion-content>
```

I also want to notice that in the .scss file. I did

```
 .contenu {
     position : absolute; 
     top : 0;
     left : 0;
     height: 100vh;
     width: 100vw;
  }
```

because the content was under the header

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem which `ion-content` had space top of it and the content started from below the header, so I solved it by moving `ion-toolbar` to my `ion-content` and fixed it position by using `slot=fixed`:

```html
<ion-content>

  <ion-toolbar slot="fixed">
    ...
  </ion-toolbar>

  ...

</ion-content>
```

```css
ion-toolbar {
  --background-color: transparent;
  --ion-color-base: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the solutions works for me (Ionic 5, Angular 11), but finally achive with:

```
ion-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and just took out the ion-toolbar. It worked!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).